# rails email function gives 501 5.1.3 Invalid address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jrubyonrails

I have this in my config file

```
myApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes                          = false
  config.action_view.debug_rjs                  = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching      = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors    = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries       = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method          = :smtp
  config.active_support.deprecation             = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings            = {
    :address => 'mailhost.mycom.com', 
    :port    => 25 
  }
end

#log ActiveRecord
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) if defined? Rails::Console
```

I am getting the error

```
scheduler caught exception :
501 5.1.3 Invalid address
classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:930:in `check_response'
classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:899:in `getok'
classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:842:in `rcptto'
classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:834:in `rcptto_list'
classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:833:in `each'
classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:833:in `rcptto_list'
classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:654:in `send_message'
/usr/local/webservices/tmp/0-odms/WEB-INF/gems/gems/mail-2.2.15/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:128:in `deliver!'
classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:526:in `start'
/usr/local/webservices/tmp/0-odms/WEB-INF/gems/gems/mail-2.2.15/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:127:in `deliver!'
/usr/local/webservices/tmp/0-odms/WEB-INF/gems/gems/mail-2.2.15/lib/mail/message.rb:1967:in `do_delivery'
/usr/local/webservices/tmp/0-odms/WEB-INF/gems/gems/mail-2.2.15/lib/mail/message.rb:228:in `deliver'
/usr/local/webservices/tmp/0-odms/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionmailer-3.0.5/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:403:in `deliver_mail'
/usr/local/webservices/tmp/0-odms/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
/usr/local/webservices/tmp/0-odms/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/usr/local/webservices/tmp/0-odms/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
/usr/local/webservices/tmp/0-odms/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionmailer-3.0.5/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:401:in `deliver_mail'
/usr/local/webservices/tmp/0-odms/WEB-INF/gems/gems/mail-2.2.15/lib/mail/message.rb:228:in `deliver'
```

I have printed out the cc/to email addresses in the log file. They are fine. the email list includes some people outside of the domain. This email typically includes an excel attachment. But wondering why I am getting this error.

Code:

```
def sendmail(co, attach)
    @co
    Rails.logger.info "co in notice : "+"#{co}"

    attachments["Report_#{co}_#{Time.now}.xls"] = {:mime_type => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                                                                                          :content => attach.string} unless attach.nil?
    mail :to => to,
         :cc => cc,
         :priority => 'Urgent',
         'X-Priority' => '1',
         :importance => 'high'
  end
```

Comment: Do you just need to add `http://` or `https://` to the address in your config?

Comment: I mean in front of the hostname such as `http://mailhost.mycom.com`

Comment: Can you post the code where you try to send the email?

Comment: I edited the post to show the code

Comment: It doesnt look like you specify the to and cc as valid fields.

Comment: Also I think you need to pass in your headers as a hash to the headers option such as `mail to: co.email, cc: "You@you.com", headers: {priority: 'Urgent', 'X-Priority' => '1', importance: :high}`. See here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#auto-encoding-header-values

Comment: the to and cc are functions, which will have the emails. I have verified the emails in the log.